# How do I charge the Proto Statue to get a Crown Vault portal?

Tags: nuclear-throne

I'm confused about how the charging of the Proto Statue works. [Nuclear Throne Wikia](http://nuclear-throne.wikia.com/wiki/Crown_Vault) says the portal charges by absorbing rads, but I'm killing enemies near the statue and the rads won't move towards it. How do I make it absorb rads and give me a Crown Vault portal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three steps required to activate the Proto Statue portal to go to the Crown Vault:

- Inactive Proto Statue

[image: Inactive Proto Statue]

When you first see a proto statue, it'll be in the inactive state shown above. Deal at least 40 points of damage to the statue to activate it for charging.

- Active Proto Statue

[image: Active Proto Statue]

Once the statue has been activated, it'll begin pulling in rads from enemies defeated around the statue. As it collects rads, the lights around the side of the statue will fill up. If the statue is destroyed before absorbing the 24 rads required to fully charge, it'll drop all absorbed rads.

- Charged Proto Statue

[image: Charged Proto Statue]

Once the statue is charged, destroy it to open the portal to the crown vault. Note that while charged, the statue will continue to absorb rads (these are lost).